# Does Visual Studio backup files when publishing a site from within VS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, publishing

When using the "publish website" functionality from Visual Studio, it deletes all what was already there, and then publishes only the files in the solution.

Does VS make a backup of the files anywhere? They're not in the recycle bin.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware it doesn't make a backup, you would need to get the files back from your backup device. You might also have some success with a file recovery tool if the directory is not backed up.